# Self-build pc won't get power

Tags: motherboard, power-supply, power

I'm trying to build a pc with only brand new bought components. After following everything by the guide of the motherboard, the pc won't turn on (pushing the button does nothing, not even a fan is spinning nor a light turns on). This isn't my first time building a pc but I've never had this problem before. These are the component I've used:

```
Motherboard: MSI X470 Gaming Plus Max
Processor: AMD Ryzen 3 3200G
Housing: Fractal Design Focus G
Power supply: Cooler Master MWE White V2 550
Memory: HyperX FURY HX426C16FB3K2/16
```

I've already found out that the power supply is working properly because using the power supply of another working pc didn't make a difference. Besides that, using a "paperclip-trick" made the fan of the power-supply spinning (as aspecten). Using another power-plug didn't make any difference either. And before you ask: I did check the I/O-power button :)

Anyone knows that could be the problem? I'm really out of ideas.

I've made some pictures so you can see how the setup is. I've removed the graphic card as it's not an essential part for starting the machine.

[image]

[image]

Comment: 1) Disconnect all power aside from the motherboard (main 24-pin and CPU power), does it turn on? 2) Connect all aside from the motherboard (main 24-pin and CPU power), does it turn on using the paperclip technique?

Comment: You say "_I did check the I/O-power button_" - are you referring to the front panel I/O connections? What about removing the power button's connector, and using a screwdriver to short the power button's pins?

Comment: Hi, I've tried both steps before but it didn't work :( it doesn't seem to be something power-related...

Comment: One thing you can try is checking whether it is the PSU or the computer. The only way I can think of is using the psu in another computer.

Comment: "_using the power supply of another working pc didn't make a difference_" - have you got this motherboard to show any signs of life? Disconnect _everything_ - all fans (except CPU fan), all USB headers and peripherals, LEDs, hard disks, keep only one stick of RAM, etc... Keep only CPU fan, 1x RAM stick, 24-pin power & CPU power.

Answer (score 0):

After returning the motherboard to the seller it appeared that the bios needed an update. So despite I've made sure that the cpu was compatible with the motherboard, that was the problem.

The seller update the bios and now everything is working properly.

Comment: While the CPU was compatible with the hardware, the firmware wasn't compatible, until it was updated.  Some motherboards allow you to update the firmware without a CPU, others require a compatible CPU in order to update the firmware, for anyone else with a similar problem the manual for the motherboard will specify this fact.